# Emotion not overriding Material UI defaults

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components, emotion

I'm trying to style a MaterialUI Typography component using the following:

```
const StyledTitleTypography = styled(Typography)`
  color: 'black';
  font-weight: 'bold';
`;

<StyledTitleTypography variant="h6" noWrap>
    test
</StyledTitleTypography>
```

yielding this:
[image: unstyled text]

however, when I style directly it works

```
<Typography variant="h6" noWrap style={{ color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
    test
</Typography>
```

yielding this: [image: styled text]

In case anyone is out there... [here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/emtion-styling?file=StyledTypography.tsx) a stackblitz demonstrating with `emotion` and `styled-components`

Answer (score 0):

So silly... copied the quotes over from the inline styling...

```
const StyledTitleTypography = styled(Typography)`
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
`;
```

works